# Reference to Multiple STI models with same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sti

I have Two STI models on User Table:

```
class Teacher < User
  has_many :parent_leads

class AppTeacher < User
  has_many :parent_leads, foreign_key: :teacher_id
```

I have relationship defined with

```
class ParentLead < Lead
```

in migration :

```
add_foreign_key :leads, :users, column: :teacher_id
```

The problem is that when running activerecord query

```
ParentLead.last.teacher
```

it queries something like this

```
  Teacher Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."type" IN ('Teacher') AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1419], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

however i want to check for both type of users (Teacher || AppTeacher)

So if i run

```
ParentLead.last.teacher
```

it should check user table for both type of user (Teacher || AppTeacher)

any suggestions will much appreciated.

Comment: Teacher / AppTeacher is a *role* played by a person, not what the person is. A person has many roles. Use composition instead of inheritance here.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly what you are looking for is a "[polymorphic-associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)"

> A slightly more advanced twist on associations is the polymorphic
>   association. With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more
>   than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might
>   have a picture model that belongs to either an employee model or a
>   product model.

Take a look on how this is setup and let me know if you still need more help.

Happy Codeing